# Unable to view models information and properties in mobile for very large files

Tags: mobile, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

As said in the title, I have a large model that has been translated to `SVF` and when I tried to view it on mobile, there are no model and properties information.

This only seems to happen on very large file as smaller files does not have this problem.

Original filesize: 1.1GB
Uploaded file type: .zip

`Chrome` - `Galaxy S5` simulation mode:
[image: No models information, console has error message "nodeAccess" undefined]

`Chrome` - `Windows PC`:
[image: Models information is shown without a problem]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For very large models, the property database is lazy loaded on mobile devices like the galaxy S5.

If the property DB is too big, it will not be able to lazy load the DB.

Unfortunately, the recommended work-around, is far more complex.

Since the galaxy device has little memory left to compute local searches, you will need to offload this local search task into the cloud.

This will involve building a server that uses the Model Derivative APIs to query instance-tree / item-property data.  You will send the query results to a custom search panel in the Forge viewer, by coding up a viewer extension.

In the meantime, I will log this as a feature-request.